# Error with attempt at polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Working on a little thing that randomly generates colored blocks. Anyway, for organization, I have each of the generators - with a method, `generate()` - in their own class, all of which descend from `Generator`. The World class holds a collection of `Generator *` to these, and so can be called as `generators[randomIndex]->generate()`.

```
//in World.h
static std::vector<Generator *> generators;

//in World.cpp
generators.push_back(&Forest());

//Generator.h
class Generator
{
public:
    virtual void generate(sf::Color ** grid, sf::Vector2i size) = 0;
};


//Forest.h
class Forest : Generator
{
public:
        void generate(sf::Color ** grid, sf::Vector2i size);
};
```

The error:

> 'type cast' : conversion from 'Forest *' to 'Generator *' exists, but is inaccessible

Why does this occur, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to inherit *publicly*:

```
class Forest : public Generator
//             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I was just interested in knowing that is this error apt for this scennario? if yes, how?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: Yes. Only public inheritance creates an "is-a" relationship upwards.

Comment: The inheritance policy sets a bar for everything being inherited and the default, as for a class definition itself, is private. So by leaving out the "public" you are saying "inherit from Generator but mark everything private". Which allows "Forest" to see everything belonging to Generator, but you cannot see it from a Forest-derived class or outside of Forest.